# Is a summation formula an object or just syntactic sugar?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, integers

This question is basically more aimed at an understanding of how certain things are formalized.
Is the addition for $\mathbb{Z}_{-k,n}$ and the $\sum_{i=-k}^n a_i$ considered as equivalent constructs? So since the $\mathbb{Z}_{-k,n}$ forms an Abelian group so does the summation formula?
Or is the summation formula just a handy notation and treating it as an object is meaningless?

Comment: If by $\mathbb{Z}_{-k,n}$ you mean the integers between $-k$ and $n$, how is that a group under addition?

Comment: @saulspatz: a) addition is commutative, symmetric and associative b) has an identity element i.e. $0$ c) has inverses e.g. $1 + (-1) = 0$

Comment: You seem to have forgotten about closure.

Comment: @saulspatz: ah I see. So then $\mathbb{Z}$ is an abelian group? So in this case the summation formula is $\sum\limits_{i=-infty}^{\infty}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is an abelian group under addition.  I really don't understand what you are getting at with your question, nor what it has to do with groups.  The summation sign is just symbol denoting a certain operation, so far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @saulspatz: I was looking at the general identities for summation here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation and I thought if we could have derived those or others similar by treating the summation formula as a distinct abstract entity that we can do operations on

Comment: In first order number,theory a summation is written as a very complicated thing. You essentially have to encode the recursive calculation into a fixed set of numbers. So the equivalent of: $\sum_{k=0}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}2$ would be almost unrecognizable to a reader.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Your exchanges with the OP dealing with "first order number theory" looks rather abstruse for me but I have no doubt it is interesting. Could you indicate a rather simple reference where I could get a little understanding of what all this is about ?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Thanks, anyway.

Comment: @JeanMarie I only know about it from a book on Hilbert’s Tenth Problem. In standard number theory, there is no symbol for exponentiation, so the only way to represent exponentiation is via a similar encoding. The solution of Hilbert’s Tenth keyed on representing exponentiation as a Diophantine equation of $n+3$ variables for some $n$, where $a=b^c$ is equivalent to $\exists x_1,\dots,x_n: P(a,b,c,x_1,\dots,x_n).$ We can write the latter in first order number theory (because $n$ is fixed, the statement does actually use dots($\dots$),) and prove it satisfies the rules of exponentiation.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I see indeed the kind of "corseting"... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As an object, if $1\le m\le n$, the summation notation $\sum_{k=m}^{k=n}$ is a linear application from the linear space ${\mathbb R}^{\mathbb N}$ of sequences of real numbers into $\mathbb R$.

More generally, if $(G,+)$ is a group commutatif, we can define $\sum_{k=m}^{k=n}$ as a morphism from the group $G^{\mathbb N}$ (group of sequences with values in $G$) into the group $G$. This means that if $\{a_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ and $\{b_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ are two sequences with values in a group $G$, then

$$
\sum_{k=m}^{k=n}(a_k+b_k)=\sum_{k=m}^{k=n}a_k+\sum_{k=m}^{k=n}b_k
$$

(If the group is not commutatif, then the application is not a morphism and I believe the convention is to use the multiplicative notation.)

Comment: I suppose the $*$ in the $(G,*)$ denotes any binary operator?

Comment: `as a morphism from the group...` I don't really understand the meaning or implication of the last sentence. Is it possible for that to be explained in simpler terms? (or even better laymen terms)?

Comment: @Jim: yes, in the notation $(G,*)$ of a group, $G$ is the underlying set and $*$ is the binary operation that satisfies the axioms of a group. Actually, the application is not a morphism of groups if the group is not commutative, so I edited the answer. In particular, I changed the notation of the operation to $+$ (as it is customary for commutative groups).